# How to change the the screensaver using terminal (without using Preference Panel)?

Tags: macos, command-line, automation, system-settings, screensaver

I would like to change the screensaver "Flurry" by the Ken Burns without using the Preference panel, directly using terminal or command.

Answer (score 5):

1. Quit System Preferences.
2. Locate the relevant plist in terminal by

   ```
   ls ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.*.plist
   ```

   You should see something like

   ```
   /Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.0B39A0DE-D1EE-59FF-85C0-6EA16FCB015B.plist
   ```

   Note that hyphen-delimited alphanumeric string. It might be host dependent, judging from that `ByHost` directory name. (Or maybe it's not. At the moment I have only one Mac at my disposal so I can't tell.)
3. In terminal, run the following commands (with the hyphen-delimited alphanumeric string replaced by what you found in the last step):

   ```
   defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.0B39A0DE-D1EE-59FF-85C0-6EA16FCB015B.plist moduleDict -dict moduleName iLifeSlideshows path /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/iLifeSlideshows.saver type 0
   defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.0B39A0DE-D1EE-59FF-85C0-6EA16FCB015B.plist
   ```

That's it. There's one problem with this approach: it seems that multiple screensavers are registered with this `iLifeSlideshows.saver` (e.g. Classic), and I couldn't locate the plist controlling which one is shown. But according my testing, if you've chosen "Ken Burns" in System Preferences and later changed it to "Flurry", then when you run the above commands you will get "Ken Burns" back. Otherwise, no guarantee — for instance, you might get "Classic" if that's the last used one from `iLifeSlideshows.saver`.

Comment: As of Monterey, the additional defaults location is com.apple.screensaver.iLifeSlideshows,

Checking `defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver.iLifeSlideshows` reveals the most recent iLife screensaver even if you have a non-iLife screen saver set as your current. 

Defaults write does not seem to be enough to change this setting however.

Comment: And then finding this solo Apple Discussion from a JAMF admin, https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7041066 , the trick for the iLife screensavers is to run `killall cfprefsd` after setting the stylekey

Answer (score 5):

Environment: 

MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)

macOS Sierra version 10.12.4

`defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver moduleDict -dict moduleName Flurry path /System/Library/Screen\ Savers/Flurry.saver/ type 0`

to check:
`defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver` 
or

```
open /System/Library/CoreServices/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine.app

## older mac OS versions pre High-sierra
## open /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app
```

adapted from here: 
http://krypted.com/mac-security/mac-setting-screen-saver-from-the-cli/

(But it needed to be updated/improved)