# just upgraded to High Sierra and cannot change screen saver anymore

Tags: high-sierra, screensaver

the screen saver always stick to Flurry

I tried the method here in

[How to change the the screensaver using terminal (without using Preference Panel)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159992/how-to-change-the-the-screensaver-using-terminal-without-using-preference-panel)

but still failed

only the `Show with clock` is working

my laptop has Airwatch Agent running