# Changing Screensaver on OSX High Sierra via Terminal

Tags: terminal, high-sierra

I am trying to change screensavers on OSX machines. However, due to the work from home setup, I am looking for a way to do this via Terminal. Do you have any tips on how to automate it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following question:
[How to change the the screensaver using terminal (without using Preference Panel)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159992/how-to-change-the-the-screensaver-using-terminal-without-using-preference-panel)

Maybe one of the existing answers can help you to archive your goal.

But this require to manipulate plist-files which can cause unwanted side effects. So be careful.