# Get lockscreen preferences with Terminal

Tags: terminal, defaults, screensaver

Can I check the preferences set for the lockscreen (time to lock, ...) with an command in the Terminal.

I tried with `defaults read /Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist` but it only outputs this:

```
{
    tokenRemovalAction = 0;
}
```

I don't know if "screensaver" is the right one. Couldn't find anything else.

Comment: Above my paygrade, but see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/84324 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159992/how-to-change-the-the-screensaver-using-terminal-without-using-preference-panel